# How can I write to one of the pvc's subpaths through unchanged path name in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

If I have a existing pvc, like

```
  volumes:
  - name: juicefs-pv
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: juicefs-pvc
```

And in k8s pod I run a framework which writing path is fixed, like `./rpc_data/rpc_dump/service_name`

How can I make the framework from differrent pod write data into pvc's corresponding subpath, such as
pod_1 run the framework write to `./rpc_data/rpc_dump/service_name` but indeed into `juicefs-pv /pod_1_path`
and pod_2 run the framework write to `./rpc_data/rpc_dump/service_name` but indeed into `juicefs-pv /pod_2_path`

```
spec:
  entrypoint: test
  templates:
    - name: test
      container:
        image: centos:8
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ["echo \"test\" > /rpc_data/rpc_dump/service_name/log.txt"]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /rpc_data/rpc_dump/service_name
          name: /data/pod_1_path
        - mountPath: /data
          name: juicefs-pv
  volumes:
  - name: juicefs-pv
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: juicefs-pvc
  ttlStrategy:
    secondsAfterCompletion: 60
  podGC:
    strategy: OnWorkflowCompletion
```

dos not work